# View related list info in infopath form

Tags: 2010, infopath

Is it possible to show a column value for an item in another list in a infopath made form? Currently the only way I have been able to do this is to pull the information from the other list and store it in a column in the other list.

Example Lists:

```
Sales Team List
ID    Item    Notes                Secret Sauce Information
1     Pants   Need to make more    [Some information R&D team can't know]

Research & Dev Team List
ID    Item    Notes                Secret Sauce Information
1     Pants   need more buttons     [Some information Sales team can't know]
```

Example Sales Team Form:

```
Item: [       ]
R&D Notes:[ View Only ]
Notes: [       ]
Secret: [       ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I edited the InfoPath form in the web-browser and added a web part to display the desired information.